# Which is the correct spot to put destination address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, tokens, contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract Forwarder {

  address public destinationAddress;
  event LogForwarded(address indexed sender, uint amount);
  event LogFlushed(address indexed sender, uint amount);

  function Forwarder() public {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  function() payable public {
    emit LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value);
    destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function flush() public {
    emit LogFlushed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    destinationAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

Please just say the spot by replying HERE1 or HERE2 blah blah as it's on the script above.

for example, my destination address where I want all eth on contract to be forwarded to is 0x7e0fE0Bd87F84906bc19438fb5F932e189Dd127e, where do I put it on the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination address is set based off who is the contract creator based off the constructor:

```
function Forwarder() public {
  destinationAddress = msg.sender;
}
```

If you want `0x7e0fE0Bd87F84906bc19438fb5F932e189Dd127e` to be the destination address, you just have to make sure that the address you mentioned is the creator of the contract.

You could also opt to replace `destinationAddress = msg.sender` with a hardcoded address, `destinationAddress = 0x7e0fE0Bd87F84906bc19438fb5F932e189Dd127e` but you shouldn't need to do that if you know how to launch contracts properly from the desired address.